# Consulting MAN pages for specific flags

Tags: shortcut, man, manual

Sometimes I want to know what a specific flag means. For instance:

```
man apache2:
(...)
-L     Output a list of directives together with expected arguments and
              places where the directive is valid.
```

So is there a way to use something like "man apache2 -L" and it tells me only what -L means? Would be great so save on browsing the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not the way you want it. But do you know that you can search inside `man`? Most systems use `less` as man browser, so you can search with the `/` command (press `h` for more help). If you look for a specific switch, you can use the fact that these are formatted with an indentation at the beginning of the line most of the time and use a regexp:

```
^[ \t]+-link
```

will search for the string `-link` as first non-whitespace character of a line. This way, you will most likely find the actual explanation of the switch and not possible references in other sections.

Comment: OK, too bad it's not possible but / will help.

Answer (score 0):

I run `man commandname` and use `/` to type a search string like your example of `-L`.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of `man` uses `less` as its pager you can use this Bash function to jump directly to the first occurrence of a given string in the `man` page:

```
mans () { local pages string; if [[ -n $2 ]]; then pages=(${@:2}); string="$1"; else         pages=$1; fi; man ${2:+--pager="less -p \"$string\""} ${pages[@]}; }
```

Usage:

```
mans '-E' grep
```

You can jump to a particular section of a series of pages:

```
mans DESCRIPTION grep sed awk
```

When you press <kbd>q</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit one `man` page and go to the next, the search will be done in it, too.